# How to remove duplicate items in sub-lists of a list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have a 2d list with more than 20 rows but Im having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to remove duplicates from each sublist in a list without changing the remaining order of unique items in each sub list. Example below,

```
list1 = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'x', 'x', 'p'], 
        ['b', 'c', 'd', 'c'], ['a', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h']]
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
Output = [['a', 'b', 'v', 'x', 'p'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'j', 'c', 'f', 'h']]
```

Comment: Try `[list(dict.fromkeys(lst)) for lst in list1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set()` can help.

`output = [list(set(l)) for l in list1]`

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` can help without changing the remaining order.

```
from collections import Counter
list(map(list,map(Counter, list1)))
```

```
[['a', 'b', 'v', 'x', 'p'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'j', 'c', 'f', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of each element? If it is an immutable data type like a int, str, tuple.. you can write like this

```
 [list(set(i)) for i in list1]
```